# How to change setup URL of pages to end with /

Tags: url

I thought that `example.com/about/` would serve `index.html` located in a directory called `about`, but if I change the address of the website to `example.com/about/index.html`, that page doesn't exist.

I have seen some websites remove the file extension from the name of a page such as from `example.com/about.html` to `example.com/about` but this is not what I want to do.

What would the name and location of the page being served be?

How can I implement this on a website made from scratch with shared hosting on a Linux server?

Comment: What's the operating system, the web server, etc.  Please edit your question to include enough details so someone can help you.

Comment: What happens when you visit `example.com/about/`? Do you have an `index.html` file in the `/about` subdirectory?? You state that your question is _not_ about removing the file extension, yet you have tagged your question `file-extension`?

Comment: On sites where URLs end in .html, this either returns a 404 or takes me to the correct page. I guess that is down to whether they have redirects in .htaccess? I have noticed that all the websites I have seen which have a url format of example.com/about/ always use a URL for the href in <a> tags. For example, href="htlps://example.com/about/" instead of href="about.html"

Comment: This doesn't necessarily have anything to do with `.htaccess`. Most sites are not plain HTML these days, so a `index.html` file probably doesn't exist. However, most sites will prevent you from accessing the `index.html` directly anyway. You need to know the difference between a URL-path and a filesystem-path. Most sites these days "design" the URL to look how they want, but this doesn't necessarily map directly to a file on the disk. However, you are talking about creating a website from scratch, so what actually is your question?

Comment: What "web server" are you using (as Trebor already asked)? You mentioned Linux (which is the OS), so this could be Apache, LiteSpeed, Nginx, ...?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide the information requested in the comments so that this can be re-opened.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single correct answer but for many sites (including WordPress) this is index.php - and this file may or may not be located in the expected place.

From a web servers POV the default file(s) it looks for and serves is usually defined in the config. On Apache Servers the directive to control this typically  DirectoryIndex. Have a look at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html for the related directives). On some servers you can control this in a .htaccess file - other servers require modification of the server config.

Another technique commonly used (eg in WordPress) is to check if a given file exists, and if not use an alternative file which can then work out the resource and display it. This is typically index.php in the root directory.  This is often affected (in Apache) with code like below ( in a fairly simple case. Sometimes in .htaccess, sometimes in the server config)

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Line 1 turns on the functionality. Lines 4 and 5 look to see that no file or directory with the given name exists and line 6 redirects the output through index.php. (Line 1 says this is being done at the web root)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the web server the browser will usually open index.html, default.html, et cetera when you go to a page that ends with a '/'.

That is in an environment that is NOT using a rewriter. Once you get into rewritten URLs, you can make no assumptions about the naming conventions on the site and the pages that power them.

And I would guess that rewritten URLs are probably the default at this point on sites that you are looking at.

On your own Linux server the default would be as you described, an index.html file in the named directory. But you can enable rewriting and change the beavior.

Comment: "the browser will usually open index.html" - to clarify, it's not the "browser" that opens this file. It is the _server_ that opens the file and the _response_ is sent back to the browser.